How can I check if my car is eligible for Glasgow low emission zone or Euro 4?
How can I check if my car is eligible for Glasgow low emission zone?
My car is on Ukrainian registration, I guess it should meet Euro-4 or Euro-6 emission standards since it is Toyota Camry Hybrid 2020 year of production, however I am not sure and I have no idea how should I check.
Do I need to register it somewhere?
Will I get fine if I don't register or have no sticker?

A diesel must be Euro 6 which came in 2014. But a hybrid is presumably petrol, which may be Euro 4, which came in 2005. So your 2020 Camry would be pretty old spec if it didn't comply. I think the first Camry hybrid was 2006, and it would be bizarre if it didn't comply with Euro 4, when the the point of hybrids is to reduce emissions.

...and I guess you would only need to register for an exemption as shown by Glasgow City Council, if the vehicle is non-compliant. If it is compliant, there is no need to register, and if it is is non-compliant, you can register it only if you are in one of the exemption classes, which is unlikely.

thanks, I am composing an answer from your comments.

So we have figured our that Toyota Camry 2020 production year is complied with Euro 6, which is even overqualified for petrol cars for LEZ.
As pointed out, since the car is compliant, we don't have to register it
https://www.glasgow.gov.uk/article/3983/Does-Your-Vehicle-Comply-with-Glasgow-s-LEZ
